# For a database of line segments, find all segments that intersect a rectangle

Tags: data-structures, geometry, computational-geometry, kdtree

Given a large set of linesegments, how do you efficiently find all line segments that intersect a rectangle? A typical application would be for a GIS database, looking up all roads that fall within the current field of view. For points this may be done efficiently by storing the points in a KD-tree, but what is the corresponding datastructure for line segments?

A bonus if the algorithm takes into account line widths, but a zero width algorithm is perfectly ok.

Answer (score 2):

You can use segment trees, like what exists in [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org): 
[dD Range and Segment Trees](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/SearchStructures/Chapter_main.html). That data structure is usable in all dimensions, including dimension 2.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the rectangle as a set of 4 line segments.
you now have a set of n+4 line segments.
apply a sweep line algorithm on the line segments.
only perform intersections if the two line segments are from different sets. I.e one segment,is frm rectangle,and the other is from the database.
Also, you may start the sweep line process from the first vertex of rectangle  and end when all rectangle lines are completely processed.

you may also search on spatial hashing and line rasterization (for filling space cells with line data)
. This may be even faster.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible data structure is the [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree).  The [priority R-tree](http://www.win.tue.nl/~mdberg/Papers/prtree.pdf) in particular will give you guaranteed upper bounds on your running time, but heuristic variants may be faster in practice.